# How to get string after specific string or keyword

Tags: node.js

I get this URL `https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris?ReturnUrl=/konsinye-hesap-sonuc&tempId=8642aa95-ebf9-4d00-8fd5-6d6c2f6023b2` I want to be able to get everything after tempId including tempId. How do I do that?

I have tried this:

```
    var pattern = "tempId=";
    var str2 = response.url().substr(response.url().indexOf(pattern), pattern.length); 
    console.log(str2);
```

How do I get to the end of string rather than just pattern's length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url) class to parse the url string, and then access the [search parameters](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams) by name, for example:

```
// Create URL object from URL string.
const myUrl = new URL('https://www.ikinciyeni.com/giris?ReturnUrl=/konsinye-hesap-sonuc&tempId=8642aa95-ebf9-4d00-8fd5-6d6c2f6023b2');
// Get tempId parameter
console.log("tempId:", myUrl.searchParams.get("tempId"));
```